# Should I use my university's letterhead for a cover letter for a job application?

Tags: job-search, application-cover-letter

I currently teach at University X and am applying for a job at University Y.  Should I write my cover letter on University X's letterhead, or use a blank page?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No. It is you as a person who is applying, not you as a representative for your university. Univ. Y would probably look very negatively on an application on such lerterhead, as would Univ. X. Letterheads are intended for your official business of your position at X as teacher, researcher etc. Applying for a job or for example writing somewhere for your private business is just that, private. You can, however, create your own private letterhead to use for such instances but this should reflect your private standing and show only private address, phone and e-mail.

So keep the official business separate from your private. As alluded to this also applies to e-mail, something most people forget about. It is good to have your own private e-mail for instances such as this.

Comment: BAM.  That's precisely the dilemma I was trying to resolve.  Thanks.

Comment: I find this attitude really different from anything I've encountered.  I have access to some job files right now, and while usage of letterhead was maybe 50/50 (I think mostly because it's a pain to get electronic letterhead that works with LaTeX from most schools), but everyone uses their professional address, email, etc.  and I think it would set off a red flag if someone didn't.  I don't especially care and am not sure I've encountered anyone who does before, but I think this answer may emphasize what *should* be done over what people actually do.

Comment: Quite. As an employer, I would not be terribly impressed that a member of staff was using my resources, whether stationery, printers or anything else, to negotiate a voluntary move to a different employer. (Had I just had to lay them off or something, that would be a different story.)

Comment: @scottishwildcat: But academia is not always like other employers.  For instance, we have fixed-term jobs (such as postdocs) which are understood to be stepping stones to more permanent positions at other institutions.  In my experience, looking for a permanent position is more or less accepted as part of a postdoc's *job*.

Comment: At least in the dim past of my youth, in academic math people _always_ used letterhead.

Comment: Fully agree with this answer. But like another user commented, it may be dependent upon the job.  If you are a postdoc and looking for a tenure track position, by all means, use the letterhead.  If you are already a tenure track and want to jump the ship to greener pastures, it's highly unethical for you to use your current letterhead. Same thing with email. Email communications at state universities and govt constitute public records and can be requested by anyone using the provisions of FOIA.

Answer (score 32):

I personally side with Peter Jansson on this one (do not use an institutional letterhead if you're not conducting business on behalf of your institution), but you will have to note that **this position is not universally shared**. I cite only one example, of [somewhat high-profile blogger/consultant](https://theprofessorisin.com/2016/08/26/why-your-job-cover-letter-sucks/), who says:

> Your letter must be on letterhead if you have a current academic affiliation of any kind. This is not negotiable.

I think it may be a field-specific and/or generation issue: some people, and some fields (humanities/law/medicine) have more attachement to older traditions and think a letterhead is a crucial part of correspondence etiquette.

Comment: I actually joined academia@stackexchange to be able to upvote this answer. Of course you should use letterhead! If you don't, University Y thinks there is some reason why University X does not want you to be affiliated with them.

Comment: @don.joey well, welcome here! I hope you stay around, it's a very nice community…

Comment: A [separate post by the same blogger](https://chroniclevitae.com/news/50-the-professor-is-in-why-letterhead-matters) indicates that there is regional and disciplinal variation in this convention. (Apparently, it is universal in the US and not used in the UK, Australia and NZ?)

Comment: @my.back Keep in mind that blogger you linked specifically provides this advice for graduate students, where it's perfectly acceptable/encouraged to use the letterhead. This is clearly not the case with other jobs where for example people may be looking to change jobs (from one tt position to another).

Answer (score 21):

I would ask a senior person in your field.  In my experience in mathematics in the US, no one gives a flying flip how you format your cover letter; in all likelihood, no one will read it.  Using department stationary is common, though far from universal and I don't think affects anyone's thinking one way or the other.

I don't think this advice is universally applicable;  I know in many other disciplines, cover letters are read carefully, and thus their professionalism will have some salutary effect.  My personal feeling is that using your current institution's letterhead, your office address, etc. looks more professional, but obviously this isn't a universal feeling, so all the more reason to check about your field specifically.

Comment: To be honest, regardless of what you use, just make sure that it is a damn good letter. Departments might have practices. Now, here is a question for others - can Bennie just call and ask?

Answer (score 15):

In academia, if you are applying for an academic position (e.g., assistant adjunct prof applying for assistant prof), regardless of whether it is at the same of different institution, it is absolutely essential that you use the letterhead for the institution with which you are currently affiliated. I realize that this is different for private companies, where "company" letterhead implies official communication on behalf of the "company."  But in academia, the letterhead is an indicator that you are recognized as a member of a scholarly community and you have the rights, privileges, and responsibilities associated with your academic appointment. In academia, it does NOT mean you are conducting official institutional business.  Official institutional business will have "Office of the Chancelor" in the letterhead or "Office of XYZ Department Chair." If the chancellor or department chair were to apply for jobs, they would probably still use institutional letterhead but not have this "Office of the __" line in the letterhead.

Using your institutional letterhead is ABSOLUTELY ESSENTIAL when applying for academic jobs. Even (especially) if you are a grad student. Everyone knows that you are not speaking on behalf of the institute, the letterhead is an indication of your membership in that scholarly community.

Comment: This answer is probably useful within the culture from which it was written, but [academia varies more than you think it does](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203). As such, this answer should be taken with a large grain of salt unless you know for a fact that it applies to your region (cf. e.g. [this link](https://chroniclevitae.com/news/50-the-professor-is-in-why-letterhead-matters)), or unless the answer gets edited to provide suitable confines in both geography and discipline.

Comment: Unless the author of this post can provide clear evidence, I think this advice is misguided and just plainly wrong on more than one level. Not using the current letterhead is not a disqualification for a new job. And using one institutions email to apply to another institution is definitely uncalled for.

Answer (score 7):

One point that I'm missing so far, but which IMHO makes quite some difference is the position which you are in:

- My "default" opionon on this question is not to use your employer's letterhead, nor your email at your employer's.
  The reason is that unless your relationship with your current employer is really bad (in which case *you* don't want to use their letterhead),  (ab)using your employer's letterhead demonstrates illoyality: not only are you not acting in as an official of your employer, but as @scottishwildcat already pointed out, you are presumably acting against your employer's interests.
- But in academia, there are certain situations where your old university is anywhere between quite happy with over positively encouraging you to expecting you to apply for another job.
  You may be in a stage of your career where a change of university is expected or at least reasonable and you and your employer agree on this (close to finishing your degree, did a postdoc abroad but want to move home again, want to move for family reasons, want to become a professor which in some countries you cannot at your "home" university, ...), or you are on a project position and for external reasons they cannot keep you.
  In this case, IMHO you may use the university letterhead (although I'd probably still not do it). But if you do so, you should make sure the university where you apply knows unambiguously that your university is happy with your application for their position, e.g. by naming your current supervisor as reference.

As for the email, free emails are available also with sober username and sober providers, so that shouldn't be a problem, neither.

Answer (score 5):

Do whatever you want.

There are strong and conflicting opinions on this ("it would set off a red flag" to not use institutional letterhead, etc. vs "I put those letters at the bottom of the pile.")

We should ask ourselves, as academics: if we are evaluating people's job applications using such incredibly fine distinctions in academic etiquette, either:

1) we are prioritizing completely useless information and probably introducing a good deal of bias against folks like international students and first-gen college students along with it!

-OR-

2) academia is so irredeemably petty that getting this right is actually an important sign of success in an academic position.

Either answer doesn't make academia sound like a place you'd want to work. I have faith that people are not actually making such important decisions using trivia. I therefore suggest that the original poster should choose whichever option allows them to make the content of their letter clearer, i.e., if you need the space for more information, don't use the letterhead!

Comment: I completely agree with everything you've written, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/57266)

Comment: @Flyto: While it may be debatable whether this post is an answer, it is certainly not a valid comment. It does not do any of the things comments are for.

Comment: Probably not - it's too long for a start. Unfortunately my comment above is that which is automatically posted when one votes to delete with the "not answer" reason.

Comment: I agree the only part that is an answer is the first line ("do whatever you want"), but I think this is a necessary corrective. The question rests on an important assumption (that there is a good answer, and people care about it), which isn't necessarily supported.

Comment: I also added an extra couple of sentences of the implications of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I fully understand the notion of not writing on letterhead except in an official capacity, but consider the tradition of using a hotel's letterhead when staying with them as a guest. I appreciate this is perhaps almost akin to sending a picture postcard (and an advertising opportunity for the hotel), yet this *clearly* is not a matter of the hotel's business activity.

This practice extended to the English with houses large enough to have guest rooms, where the etiquette is to provide headed notepaper of your own for your guests to use.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. While your post provides a new and valid outlook on OPs question, I would still like to see how it relates to OPs specific case.

Answer (score -3):

Completely agree that you should not use letterhead from the academic institution you are trying to leave.  I put those letters at the bottom of the pile when reviewing job applications for teaching positions.  Only caveat is when you hold a postdoc, but if you are tenure track or more, then no, use your own.

Comment: Exactly what part of the criteria listed in the job advertisement makes it reasonable for you to disregard letters written on letterhead? Does it indicate an inability to do research? To teach? Does the advertisement clearly state that applications on letterhead will be disregarded?

Comment: I didn't say they would be disregarded, just put at the bottom of the pile, like those with bad writing or less than wonderful vitae.  If the rest is amazing it may rise up again but the choice to use letterhead shows poor judgement. If you don't want to be at an institution that is currently paying your salary and expecting you to stay, don't use their letterhead.

Comment: I think inferring poor judgement from the use of a letterhead shows poor judgement. I would not expect a good working environment from an academic institution that uses such practices, and they would be put at the bottom of the pile.